# How to serve next js app using keystonejs?

Tags: next.js, keystonejs

I have a problem with serving next js app using keystonejs. I want to achive something similar like in to do nuxt example which you can choose while creating keystone project. I used code from this link https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/app-next/ in index.js file, but I get an error while trying to run the app:

ReferenceError: distDir is not defined at Object.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you define your `distDir` var anywhere?

Comment: I tried to, but i am not sure what to assign to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have in my setup

create `app` folder (next js code)
create `next.config.js` in `app` folder

my `next.js.config` file has following code

```
const distDir = 'dist';
module.exports = {
  distDir: `../${distDir}/www`,
  env: {
    SERVER_URL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:4000',
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    // staticFolder: '/static',
  },
};
```

it export the build artifacts in `dist/www` in root of keystone project.